# MariaDB upgrade from 10.5 to 10.6: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, upgrade, mariadb-10.5

I have a MariaDB 10.5 instance running on a OpenSUSE Leap 15.3 server (PHP 7.4.6).

I'm not able to follow the [official upgrade documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/upgrading-from-mariadb-105-to-mariadb-106/) for the installation was made through official SLE repositories (last available version still being 10.5) and not from MariaDB one. Then, here is what I have achieved so far:

- Import MariaDB repository key:

`rpm --import https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB`

- Add MariaDB specific repository for 10.6 version:

`sudo zypper addrepo --gpgcheck --refresh https://yum.mariadb.org/10.6/opensuse/15/x86_64 mariadb`

- Install MariaDB 10.6:

`sudo zypper install MariaDB-server MariaDB-client`

- Choose solution 1 being uninstalling 10.5 packages (when prompted)
- Start `mariadb` service using `systemctl start mariadb`.

I then get the right version using `mariadb --version`.

I'm now able to connect to mariadb locally using `mariadb -u root -p` and to list my databases.

Issues are:

- I'm not able to connect to phpMyAdmin. Connection page is loading properly but I get the following error message:

> mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory

- My applications are not working. It seems there is a problem for connecting to MariaDB service. Example for GLPI:

> PHP Warning:  mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /var/www/glpi/src/DBmysql.php on line 248
> A link to the SQL server could not be established. Please check your configuration.

Something was broken when reinstalling MariaDB and I can't find out where...

---

**EDIT:**

Here are some additional informations, based on @Georg Richter suggestion (see answers).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like PHP on your system is not properly configured, since connection attempt fails due to missing unix socket.

Check the location of unix_socket, e.g. with command line client:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> \s
--------------
<snip>
UNIX socket:            /tmp/mysql.sock
<snap>
```

Now make sure that the PHP settings for mysqli have the same settings, e.g. with

```
php -i | grep socket
```

or by checking your php configuration file.

Comment: Thanks for help! I updated initial post with a screenshot of the commands I passed. The Unix socket was not the same in MariaDB and in PHP configuration file. Strangely, `php -i | grep socket` returns a value for `mysqli.default_socket` whereas php.ini file contains no value for this parameter. Could you have a look at the post update?

Comment: I eventually had to modify the `mysqli.default_socket` parameter in `/etc/php7/apache2/php.ini`. This corrected the problem.